# Мониторинг загрузки сервера на сайте

Tags: php, centos7, httpd

Как получить данные из файла /proc/stat средствами php и вывести их на сайт(админку), при этом  чтобы соответствующий скрипт находился в каталоге сайта /var/www/user/site?

Comment: https://github.com/phpsysinfo/phpsysinfo - думаю должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо,конечно,но хотелось бы свой простенький велосипед...

Comment: Поковырять проект и посмотреть каким образом он это делает и на основе полученных знаний сделать свой?

Comment: Да,пожалуй,так и сделаю. Спасибо!